# How to use img source binding in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-vue

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4 my-5"><mark>GIGS</mark></h1>
        <b-container fluid="lg">
            <b-row class="mx-auto">
                <b-col lg="4" class="my-4" v-for='gig in gigs' :key='gig'>
                    <a :href="gig.url" target="_blank"><img :src="'./assets/' + gig.img" width="250" height="250" class="border border-success rounded-circle"/></a>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-container>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            gigs: [
                {
                    project: "Spotify",
                    url: "https://www.spotify.com/us/",
                    img: "spotify.png"
                },
                {
                    project: "Khan Academy",
                    url: "https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_385372636982405710465563/courses",
                    img: "khan.png"
                },
                {
                    project: "City International Co.",
                    url: "http://www.cityinternationalco.com/",
                    img: "hvac.png"
                },
            ],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here in this code i used `:src="'./assets/' + gig.img"` which should show my image on the screen. Also when i inspect element i see the correct src address but somehow the img is not showing on the screen. it's only showing the green border of the image, rounded as styled in code but still does not show the actually image. I don't really know what can i do here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I assume it should be ':src="'./assets/' + 'gig.img'"' or even ':src="'./assets/gig.img"' or if this is constant address then src="./assets/gig.img"

Comment: @Anatoly - `gig.img` is the name of the file, based on the `data` attribute. If you put quotes around it, it will just become a string.

Comment: My bad didn't notice it in v-for!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use require to get an imagen from assets folder:

```
<img :src="require('./assets/' + gig.img)" width="250" height="250" class="border border-success rounded-circle"/>
```

Comment: do you get any warning?